# Validate if big decimal is created without any precision loss

Tags: double, bigdecimal

I have a method which accepts BigDecimal. I want to make sure its decimal value have no precision loss (i.e) input to big decimal is exactly stored as it is. My understanding is that precision loss happens when I try to convert infinite double to big decimal and so, it is recommended to create big decimal using string representation of double. Basically, I want to make sure if big decimal is constructed using BigDecimal(String) for such infinite doubles.

As per my understanding after going through [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)), input double value which results in precision loss during big decimal conversion always have very large magnitude which won't fit in 64 bits. Example: 0.1. So, string and double value representation of such big decimals won't match. is it enough to say that precision loss has occurred when string and double value won't match?
Eg:
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(0.1);
System.out.println(decimal.toString()) // prints 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
System.out.println(decimal.doubleValue()) // prints 0.1.
String and double value of big decimal differ and so, precision loss happened.

Comment: I don't understand your question completely nor your example, especially your second paragraph, but in general you cannot be certain how the BigDecimal was constructed. First of all, doubles obviously represent some values exactly, and every numerical value that double can represent exactly can also be represented exactly as a BigDecimal. e.g `new BigDecimal(.3125)` is the same number as `new BigDecimal(".3125")`. Secondly, the division of two BigDecimal  may result in in a value that cannot be represented exactly as a BigDecimal.

Comment: My intention is to capture those inputs which resulted in precision loss.  In the example you provided, the input will be stored as it is in BigDecimal even if we  use double. There are some numbers like 0.1 which cannot be stored as it is if we use double. In suc cases, we need to pass those values as string to BigDecimal. So, once i have BigDecimal, is ther

Comment: In connection with the second paragraph, if a BigDecimal resulted from conversion of a finite double number, its doubleValue() will be the double you started with. Conversion from double to BigDecimal is exact for finite numbers. Conversion of a BigDecimal to double is exact if the value of the BigDecimal can be represented as a double, which will be the case if you started with a finite double number.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan So, I believe my understanding is correct then. If we are converting infinite double like 0.1 to BigDecimal, then only we will end up with precision loss (i.e) 0.1 will be actually stored as something else (as highlighted above) in big decimal. So, it is recommended to create big decimal from string "0.1" for such infinite numbers. For finite double , we can create big decimal using string representation or double itself. There won't be any precision loss at all. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @explorer I agree with your comment, except for how you are using "infinite double", which has a very specific meaning. The problem is with trying to guess after the fact where a BigDecimal came from. Do you consider BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal("3"), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN) to be valid or invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This idea breaks down if you allow the BigDecimal to be the result of arithmetic.

If you are going to require the BigDecimal to be the direct, unmodified result of conversion of a decimal string it would be much simpler to require a String argument and convert it to BigDecimal in your method.

The following program is an attempt to implement and test your validity check. The variable `third` was calculated without any involvement of doubles, using only decimal strings and BigDecimal, but fails the test.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal third = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal("3"), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        testIt(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
        testIt(new BigDecimal(0.1));
        testIt(third);
    }

    static void testIt(BigDecimal in) {
        System.out.println(in+" "+isValid(in));
    }

    static boolean isValid(BigDecimal in) {
        double d = in.doubleValue();
        String s1 = in.toString();
        String s2 = Double.toString(d);
        return s1.equals(s2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.1 true
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 false
0.333333333333333333333333333333 false
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am also more inclined with accepting the value as String and then converting it to BigDecimal internally. Though the arithmetic example is good one, we will not have the problem because the input decimal comes from JSON or manual input.